# How to stop "NTFS new version", or any notification for that matter?

Tags: macos, mojave, notifications, ntfs

I used paragon NTFS for a while and then deleted it from applications folder. I also removed the dmg file(I know it would not stop notifications).

But I keep getting notifications like this everyday.

[image: notif].

Clicking on it is useless. Safari would open(if not already) but no new window, no webpage, nothing.

I searched the Library folder for NTFS and paragon and deleted files and folders for e.g. from application support, from caches. One folder in its name had "notification". I deleted that too. Unhid hidden files by `CMD + Shift + .` For a temporary fix, I turned off notification from System Preferences. **But I need a permanent fix.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any App you need to actually run an installer & give admin perms, rather than just drag to Applications, installs elements somewhere inside the 'system' itself.

It is not wise to just throw these out if you no longer want them, as they will leave all the system bits behind.

As you threw away the component which contains the uninstaller, the app itself, then by far the simplest way to uninstall it will be to get the installer again, install it, then use its own uninstaller to uninstall it.
At the moment it is still entirely functional, you only threw out the control surface.

[image]

Comment: I just got another concern. After confirming the "Uninstall" or not, I got the restart or not popup. I, in the hurry of getting it uninstalled, pressed it. My Mac shut down instantly and did not restart. I bore the pointer on the black screen for a while before holding down the power button and then pressing it again to get my Mac functional. Then a dialog box appears saying that my Mac restarted due to a problem, should it open the previously opened applications? Mac should have asked me this before shutting down or atleast giving me some time. This also means that any app can do this too!

Comment: Something crashed. That's all we can tell from that. Whether it was the uninstaller or not, maybe the panic report would show.

Comment: The app was the cause of the restart notification. It was not the native box. That means any app can simulate a human click on such a dialog box. Also, some items on the web don't ship uninstaller and tell people to delete things the way I did. But I should have checked the dmg first. Thank you!

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me after trying system preferences etc.

Answer (score 1):

Open System Preferences app → Notifications, find the application (I'm guessing it would be Paragon NTFS or something similar in this case), set the alert style to none and disable all the checkboxes below.

- [Use Notifications on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204079)

For the Paragon NTFS specific notifications, it sounds like you may have some component still installed.

Check that there's nothing under System Preferences app → Users & Groups → *Logged in user* →  Login Items for Paragon NTFS, that there isn't anything installed via the macOS App Store, and that there aren't any processes running for it when you look in the Activity Monitor application.

Comment: 1. Okay maybe I "mis"phrased my question. I wanted to remove the notification causing agent altogether, Not hiding something which is going on under the hood anyway. 2. Nothing under login items. 3. Yes NTFS and paragon appear in activity Monitor. Use memory and CPU also.